# matplotlib convert real to categorical

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

If i have a set of data

`python
x_data = array([-0.5597064565292805, -0.6044992007582148, 0.22877491676881043,
       -1.2332817779977419, 0.42077626119484773, 1.825509016838052,
       0.3476645527864688, -0.35439666443655543, 0.8783711637081933,
       -0.438777582274935], dtype=object)`

I can't get matplotlib to draw a bar chart with x as categorical values. No matter what I do, it forces a convert to real. Any ideas how to make each number a categorical?

Comment: "Convert to real"? Are they not reals? They certainly look it judging by your limited code excerpt.

Comment: What is your Y?

Comment: My y_data is also random normals. I want to generate a bar chart. Making the x scale linear causes the bars to overlap, while treating them as categorical would cause them to be separate. Does that make sense?

Comment: I tried converting them to strings, to objects, but couldnt get mpl to generate a categorical scale for the x axis. Essentially, I want to treat each x value like it was just some string,

Comment: PS, if I wanted to save the image as a 64pixel by 64pixel image - how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can plot your y data as a function of the numbers 0,1,2,3, etc and then set the ticklabels as the strings from the x_data.

[image]

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = [-0.5597064565292805, -0.6044992007582148, 0.22877491676881043,
       -1.2332817779977419, 0.42077626119484773, 1.825509016838052,
       0.3476645527864688, -0.35439666443655543, 0.8783711637081933,
       -0.438777582274935]

y_data = np.random.rand(len(x_data))

x_strings=["{:.3f}".format(x) for x in x_data]

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=64./5)
plt.bar(range(len(x_data)), y_data )
plt.xticks(range(len(x_data)), x_strings)

plt.savefig(__file__+".png", dpi="figure")
plt.show()
```

The result as a 64x64 pixel image would look like

[image]

where nothing is readable. So it may not make too much sense.

Comment: Thanks so much. Its for an image recognition problem. I didn't realize it would be so complicated to specify in mpl. In https://github.com/bloomberg/bqplot, you can specify the "scale" (using Wilkinson terminology) directly - so passing an OrdinalScale does it pretty well